# Pc warmimg up and direct off

Tags: windows-7

My pc windows 7 warming up and direct off after 20 minutes in summer hot days. In my computer room I have no window. I put a fan (I mean cleaned motherboard core fan, but didn't clean smps fan) but this is same problem.

How to solve this problem?

I does not can any work on this. I am learning web designing.

Comment: "I put a fan" Do you mean to the room or for the computer? Did you try cleaning the computer fans if there is dust caked on them?

Comment: No, i mean i clean motherboard core fan. But don't clean smps fan.

Comment: I put a fan to the room.

Comment: Are you certain that the fan in the computer is working?

Comment: Yes, in my cpu has two fan and they are working.

Comment: How old is the pc? Is it a laptop or desktop? What are the temperatures of the pc (open hardware monitor can show you this)

Comment: If it is heat related, I'm guessing either the fans are blocked or the cpu needs some new thermal paste between it and the heatsink.

Comment: Pc is 10 months old only. It is desktop. I don't show.

Comment: Yes it's heats up after 20 minutes and direct off automatically

Comment: A quick test to see if it really is heat related is to take the case cover off and point a window fan directly at the motherboard. Be careful not to touch the exposed motherboard or components. It ought to transfer enough air to draw heat away even if you have dust buildup etc. If you have kids pets, etc around, don't let them near it while you test this.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC or more precisely your CPU is overheating. Most modern computers have heat censors that monitor the temperature and will turn off the PC if the temperature gets too high. Get a free tool to measure the CPU temperature and monitor how high it gets before the PC turns off. That will tell you if it's the CPU overheating. Anything over 70-80 degrees is too high. If that is indeed the issue, replacing the CPU fan will help but you also have to apply thermal compound on the CPU itself before you put the fan on top of it to help with the heat transfer.